# Do ceiling roses need to be moved when earthing lights?

Tags: lighting

I was advised by a letting agent that lights in my house all needed earthing in order to let it. I agreed and paid for their contractor to do the work. I later discovered that all the ceiling roses had been moved several inches across the ceilings leaving unsightly patches of poor plastering and, according to the tenant, holes in the ceilings.
The reason given when I queried this was that the wiring was encased in metal conduits and it was a big job. I don't understand from that why it was absolutely necessary to cut new holes and move the roses. 
Could the job have been completed without moving the ceiling roses? If so what  would an electrician have needed to do and would it have cost a lot more? [image]

Comment: My first reaction is that you have been victimized, but certainly something was not explained to you ahead of time because this is absolutely not acceptable. If the rosettes did in fact have to be moved (which I doubt), then this ceiling repair is not acceptable. I would like to hear what @RedGrittyBrick has to say about this.

Comment: Are the rosettes now off center in the rooms?! Have you already paid all the billed charges?

Comment: Wow why would they need to move things this sounds crazy to me, conduit is a way to ground or earth a fixture and if that did not meet your local code a new ground or earthing wire could be pulled in the conduit Without moving the fixture, next that patch job looks like a 3 year old child's art project with the patch compound and a slingshot I would not consider this even close to professional work and if the conduit was metal the fixtures were already grounded I think you were scammed.

Comment: You should get an opinion from an expert in UK wiring.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The house was council built in the late 60's and was privately owned from about 1990. The metal conduits encased the original wiring. I paid the bill as I had moved out and was unaware of the state of the work or that the roses had been moved until I inspected the property a few weeks ago. I am now now trying to get opinions from quaulified electricians so i can challenge the agent as i believe i have been taken for a fool. I was not consulted on any of the work or made aware they were moving roses.

Comment: Your comments are really helpful. Thank you so much. I need to challenge the agent but he has fobbed me off or ignored me in the past and is doing same with my concerns this time so I'm trying to gather  as much information as possible.

Answer (score 4):

> **Do ceiling roses need to be moved when earthing lights?**

In general, no.

---

> **lights in my house all needed earthing**

I'm surprised that your UK house had no earth wires in the lighting circuit. So far as I know it has been [standard since at least 1966 (14th Edition)](http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php/Wiring_regs_history).

In addition, so far as I know, many or most ceiling or pendant lights have no *exposed conductive parts* and no *[extraneous conductive parts](https://www.voltimum.co.uk/articles/guide-determination-extraneous)*. There is often nothing exposed below the ceiling that can be earthed even if you wanted to.

---

> **Could the job have been completed without moving the ceiling roses?**

Yes.

I know of no compelling reason to change the location of the ceiling roses.

> **If so what would an electrician have needed to do**

My guess is that there was a problem with the condition and resistance/continuity of the existing [conduit used as an earth](https://www.voltimum.co.uk/articles/guide-verification-steel-conduit) (more properly called a circuit protective conductor or CPC nowadays).

Running a new earth wire through a conduit can be troublesome and many electricians might not be willing to attempt it. It seems plausible that the electrician abandoned the use of the old conduit and ran new twin and earth (T&E) cable alongside without taking the time to remove any of the existing conduit.

This might have made it difficult to run the new wiring to the places occupied by the now-disused conduit or by fittings associated with it.

> **and would it have cost a lot more?**

If my guesses above are right, it would have taken more time to remove the ends of existing conduit and properly deal with the associated old wiring.

We don't know exactly what the electrician did or what other options were available to them. Having a letting agent act as a middleman may have meant there was no opportunity for you and the electrician to discuss options.

---

This work doesn't seem to have properly met your needs. Note that I am not a qualified electrician - you might like to get an independent assessment from a reputable firm.

I suspect your main concern is the poor quality of the visible remedial work. If so, it might be best to focus on that.

---

The quality of the workmanship on the repair to the ceiling is certainly very poor. I would say that is unacceptable. I think you have reasonable grounds to complain to the letting agents about the work carried out by their contractor.

Comment: The metal conduit encased the original wiring. I have  een told by a neighbour that the conduuts were the earth but he is not an electrician although he knows quite a bit. The light roses were all off centre in the upstairs rooms originally. I privately own the house but have moved in with my partner and rent my house for a source of income. I am getting legal advice but have been told I need opinions from electricians on order to challenge the agent. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: @Lynne, UK regulations do allow the [use of metal conduit as an earth conductor](https://www.voltimum.co.uk/articles/guide-verification-steel-conduit) (CPC) - it must be tested and any breaks in continuity fixed. Running new T&E cable alongside the now-disused conduit might have motivated the relocation of the ceiling roses. Removing some or all of the existing conduit would have allowed the re-use of the old ceiling rose locations.

Comment: I would guess that the handyman they brought in was a dunce, and only knew how to run twin-and-earth and all he knew about those silly pipe thingies is it's really hard to put twin-and-earth in them, so he moved the rose to not deal with them.  The conduit, which is the more professional way to do the job, is probably still in the wall, still intact and still going to the original rose location.